# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I am trying to make Selenium automatically open a webpage in Chrome.
This is my code...

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get("https://www.python.org/")


element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("q")


print(element.click())
```

This is the error...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

I see there are 2 problems here:

1. You have to add delay before `element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("q")` to let the page load.
   Preferably you should use `visibility_of_element_located` expected condition for this.
2. I see no element with link text equals to `q` there